# Exist any delphi class to parse .plist osx files

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm looking if exist a delphi class to parse [plist](http://www.appleexaminer.com/MacsAndOS/Analysis/PLIST/PLIST.html) osx files or I must just parse these files like a normal XML file?

Comment: I would look for the Cocoa wrapper that reads the PLIST files. Maybe there is already one in the Mac OS platform apis in Delphi? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5

Comment: +1 off: I don't get why people are down voting questions like this, it's pure evil. on: I think you should try to parse it yourself, maybe give omnixml.com a try?

Comment: +1 It's a usefull question! Delphi is multiplatform.

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: A property list file is generally an XML file but it can be also in a binary format.

Comment: https://github.com/SirRufo/PropertyList will read, write and manage XML plist files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

- Address the eventual binary plist format to XML plist conversion.
- Parse the XML (plist) the usual way.

As a starting point, I recommend the excellent work of **Alexey Dolgopolov** done in [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal): **BPlis2Xml**.

https://bitbucket.org/alexeydl/develnotes/downloads/bpist2xml.zip

I wish you good luck.

**Last edit:**

Another [c](/questions/tagged/c) first hand interesting resource from Apple Inc is available [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c).

Comment: +1 super, now I have a starting point for when I move to osx, if ever (:

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: You are welcome. As a regular visitor of your site, I appreciate what you've done to our Delphi community and somewhere in my box there is a folder named after you full of "gems".

Comment: wow, didn't knew, glad that someone finds those stuff useful!